# Выделить по клику число в месяце

Tags: javascript, html

Прошу подсказать, как по клику выделить определенную дату и как эту выбранную дату связать с файлом Базы Данных для последующего выбора информации в ней на выбранную нами дату.

```html
<style>
#calendar2 {
  width: 18.75em;
  font: monospace;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
#calendar2 thead tr:last-child {
  font-size: small;
  color: #000;
}
#calendar2 thead tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) {
  color: black;
}
#calendar2 thead tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1):hover, #calendar2 thead tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2):hover, #calendar2 thead tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(4):hover, #calendar2 thead tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(5):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#calendar2 thead tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) {
  color: green;
}

#calendar2 tbody td.drugie {
  color: rgb(44, 86, 122);
  cursor: pointer;
}
#calendar2 tbody td:nth-child(n+6), #calendar2 .holiday {
  color: rgb(231, 140, 92);
}
#calendar2 tbody td.today {
  background: rgb(220, 0, 0);
  color: #fff;
}
</style>

<table id="calendar2">
  <thead>
    <tr><td><<</td><td><</td><td colspan="3"></td><td>></td><td>>></td>
    <tr><td>Пн</td><td>Вт</td><td>Ср</td><td>Чт</td><td>Пт</td><td>Сб</td><td>Вс</td>
  <tbody>
</table>

<script>
function Calendar2(id, year, month) {
var Dlast = new Date(year,month+1,0).getDate(),
    D = new Date(year,month,Dlast),
    DNlast = new Date(D.getFullYear(),D.getMonth(),Dlast).getDay(),
    DNfirst = new Date(D.getFullYear(),D.getMonth(),1).getDay(),
    calendar = '<tr>',
    month=["Январь","Февраль","Март","Апрель","Май","Июнь","Июль","Август","Сентябрь","Октябрь","Ноябрь","Декабрь"];
if (DNfirst != 0) {
  for(var  i = 1; i < DNfirst; i++) calendar += '<td>';
}else{
  for(var  i = 0; i < 6; i++) calendar += '<td>';
}
for(var  i = 1; i <= Dlast; i++) {
  if (i == new Date().getDate() && D.getFullYear() == new Date().getFullYear() && D.getMonth() == new Date().getMonth()) {
    calendar += '<td class="today">' + i;
  }else{
    calendar += '<td class="drugie">' + i;
  }
  if (new Date(D.getFullYear(),D.getMonth(),i).getDay() == 0) {
    calendar += '<tr>';
  }
}
for(var  i = DNlast; i < 7; i++) calendar += '<td>&nbsp;';
document.querySelector('#'+id+' tbody').innerHTML = calendar;
document.querySelector('#'+id+' thead td:nth-child(3)').innerHTML = month[D.getMonth()] +' '+ D.getFullYear();
document.querySelector('#'+id+' thead td:nth-child(3)').dataset.month = D.getMonth();
document.querySelector('#'+id+' thead td:nth-child(3)').dataset.year = D.getFullYear();
if (document.querySelectorAll('#'+id+' tbody tr').length < 6) {  // чтобы при перелистывании месяцев не "подпрыгивала" вся страница, добавляется ряд пустых клеток. Итог: всегда 6 строк для цифр
    document.querySelector('#'+id+' tbody').innerHTML += '<tr><td>&nbsp;<td>&nbsp;<td>&nbsp;<td>&nbsp;<td>&nbsp;<td>&nbsp;<td>&nbsp;';
}
}
Calendar2("calendar2", new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate());

// переключатель минус месяц
document.querySelector('#calendar2 thead tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)').onclick = function() {
  Calendar2("calendar2", document.querySelector('#calendar2 thead td:nth-child(3)').dataset.year, parseFloat(document.querySelector('#calendar2 thead td:nth-child(3)').dataset.month)-1);
}
// переключатель плюс месяц
document.querySelector('#calendar2 thead tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(4)').onclick = function() {
  Calendar2("calendar2", document.querySelector('#calendar2 thead td:nth-child(3)').dataset.year, parseFloat(document.querySelector('#calendar2 thead td:nth-child(3)').dataset.month)+1);
}


// переключатель минус год
document.querySelector('#calendar2 thead tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)').onclick = function() {
  Calendar2("calendar2", parseFloat(document.querySelector('#calendar2 thead td:nth-child(3)').dataset.year)-1, (document.querySelector('#calendar2 thead td:nth-child(3)').dataset.month));
}
// переключатель плюс год
document.querySelector('#calendar2 thead tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(5)').onclick = function() {
  Calendar2("calendar2", parseFloat(document.querySelector('#calendar2 thead td:nth-child(3)').dataset.year)+1, (document.querySelector('#calendar2 thead td:nth-child(3)').dataset.month));
}


// переключатель даты


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

для выделения можно добавить такой код через jq(недавно нашел). а остальное не знаю

```js
$('td').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('grey');
});
```

```css
td.grey{
  background: rgba(189, 195, 199, 0.7);
  border-radius: 0 20px;
  height: 100%;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/dduckker/pen/pmopqq тут показано как работает

Comment: Спасибо.... с выделением почти то, что надо.. Только при клике на "новую" дату в Вашем варианте не снимается выделение предыдущей...